# Magento 2 weird error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

[image]

When I click this setting icon I get this following error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested product doesn't exist

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested product doesn't exist
#0 /var/www/html/isac-test/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Form.php(150): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->getById('50', false, '1')
#1 /var/www/html/isac-test/app/design/frontend/Altius/isec/Magento_Catalog/templates/custom/review-form.phtml(156): Magento\Review\Block\Form->getProductInfo()
#2 /var/www/html/isac-test/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/i...')
#3 /var/www/html/isac-test/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Review\Block\Form), '/var/www/html/i...', Array)
```

I deployed, compiled but couldn't identify why this error occurs.

Comment: Can you please run these both commnd php bin/magento indexer:reindex   and php bin/magento cache:clean. Check again adding the product to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

update this file vendor/magento/module-review/Block/form.php

```
protected function getProductId()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
}
```

to this code

```
protected function getProductId()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id', false);
}
```